# How to sort an ArrayList of Objects (Player Names and Player Scores)

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I try solve this but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, has passed 7 days for trying a lot of things, I need help solve it please and I think the mistake is on my created class.

I have 4 players with 4 text view and 4 other text view for the score of the players. Also I have made a new other 4 textviews for the place1, place2, place3, place4. What I want to do is that I need to sort scores and display them in place1, place2, place3, place4 along with the name of that player who has that score.

What I did until now is that I created my class into the main activity above the `onCreate` section

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //my created class
    class JucatorScor {

        public String Name;
        public int Scor;

        public JucatorScor (String sName, int iScor) {
            this.Name = sName;
            this.Scor = iScor;
        }
    }

    //begin oncreate
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    //end oncreate
}
```

And I also have a button, when I click it, read my values from the text view name of players, score of players and after sorting the array display place1, place2, place3, place4 like this:

```
//begin button click
public void sorteazaCLICK (View view) {

    //initialization place1, place2, place3, place4 where i will put the sorting value
    TextView varPozitia1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc1);
    TextView varPozitia2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc2);
    TextView varPozitia3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc3);
    TextView varPozitia4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc4);

    //initialization name of players
    TextView varNumeJucator1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc1);
    String sNameJuc1;
    sNameJuc1 = varNumeJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varNumeJucator2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc2);
    String sNameJuc2;
    sNameJuc2 = varNumeJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varNumeJucator3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc3);
    String sNameJuc3;
    sNameJuc3 = varNumeJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varNumeJucator4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc4);
    String sNameJuc4;
    sNameJuc4 = varNumeJucator1.getText().toString();

    //initialization scores
    TextView varScorJucator1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc1);
    String t1;
    t1 = varScorJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varScorJucator2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc2);
    String t2;
    t2 = varScorJucator2.getText().toString();

    TextView varScorJucator3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc3);
    String t3;
    t3 = varScorJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varScorJucator4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc4);
    String t4;
    t4 = varScorJucator1.getText().toString();


    //transform the values from text view scores into integer
    int iScorJuc1;
    iScorJuc1 = Integer.parseInt(t1);

    int iScorJuc2;
    iScorJuc2 = Integer.parseInt(t2);

    int iScorJuc3;
    iScorJuc3 = Integer.parseInt(t3);

    int iScorJuc4;
    iScorJuc4 = Integer.parseInt(t4);


    ArrayList<JucatorScor> arrJucatorScor = new ArrayList<>(4);


        //building manually the array list
        arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc1, iScorJuc1));  //position 0
        arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc2, iScorJuc2));  //position 1
        arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc3, iScorJuc3));  //position 2
        arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc4, iScorJuc4));  //position 3

    Collections.sort(arrJucatorScor, new Comparator<JucatorScor>() {

        //sorting my object array depending on scores
        @Override
        public int compare(JucatorScor o1, JucatorScor o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.Scor).compareTo(o2.Scor);
        }

    });


    //here display them from bigger to smaller according to eatch place1, place2, place3, place4
    varPozitia1.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(3)));
    varPozitia2.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(2)));
    varPozitia3.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(1)));
    varPozitia4.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(0)));

} //end button click
```

The problem is that when I click the button don't put on place1, place2, place3, place4 the name and the score sorted... just appear some thing like in this photo:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you use the `toString()` method of `JucatorScor` to render the objects :

```
varPozitia1.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(3)));
varPozitia2.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(2)));
varPozitia3.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(1)));
varPozitia4.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(0)));
```

What you see in your screen is a default implementation `toString()` provided by a base class.

Either you implement `toString()` with the wished text

Or the other solution is to perform the rendering in a helper method and that also sets the suitable `String` in the `TextView`:

```
public set renderTopJucatorScor(JucatorScor jucatorScor, int ranking, TextView varPozitia){    
    varPozitia.setText("Loc" + ranking +  " = " + jucatorScor.getName() + jucatorScor.getScore());
}
```

Then you can call the helper method like that :

```
renderTopJucatorScor(varPozitia1, arrJucatorScor.get(3), 1);
renderTopJucatorScor(varPozitia2, arrJucatorScor.get(2), 2);
renderTopJucatorScor(varPozitia3, arrJucatorScor.get(1), 3);
renderTopJucatorScor(varPozitia4, arrJucatorScor.get(0), 4);
```

Comment: thanks very much for the answer...but... i dont understand..can u example me with code pls?

i tryed this to put on my class

@Override
        public String toString() {
            return Name + " " + Scor;
        }

but not show corectlly the results :((

i tryed using your renderTopJucatorScor but the set is in red and i dont know where to put that code? in a class or into the button click?

Comment: You are welcome. If you add the toString() method in the JucatorScor  class, it should work. Have you noticed any change on the rendering? If you see nothing maybe the compiled code is not updated.

Comment: my created class look like this now

class JucatorScor {

        public String Name;
        public int Scor;

        public JucatorScor (String sName, int iScor) {
            this.Name = sName;
            this.Scor = iScor;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Name + " " + Scor;
        }

    }

this is all the changes i maded only in the class
and when i run the app..the display results are like this

Place1   =   Aladin 550
Place2   =   Aladin 120
Place3   =   Aladin 120
Place4   =   Aladin 120

Comment: You have made an inattention error in your initial code when you want to get the score of the third and the fourth textView. You still use varScorJucator1 instead of varScorJucator3 and varScorJucator4:   `TextView varScorJucator3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc3);
    String t3;
    t3 = varScorJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varScorJucator4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc4);
    String t4;
    t4 = varScorJucator1.getText().toString();T
`

Comment: omg....thanks a lot my friend....also i have descovered other mistakes.. thanks to you...you just have saved me. Now after i repaired the code on the initialization, everything works perfectly... i will post the correct code , maybe will help other people too.

Comment: The end is happy :) To avoid this kind of problem you should favor the use of helper method as I done in my answer rather than doing copy/paste that is easy but that also creates the risk to reusing the bad variable. For example the three instructions to get the score of each textview could be in a helper method that returns a String.

Comment: Ohh, thanks also for this, but already i have a good solution that is working and i can use from now on anywhere i will need it. This is just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

After discovering ( with the help of user "davidxxx" ), some mistakes into my initialization of textviews, finnaly i have managed to solve the problem. Also i added into my created class a method: toString.

The correct solution is this:

```
//my created class
class JucatorScor {

    public String Name;
    public int Scor;

    public JucatorScor (String sName, int iScor) {
        this.Name = sName;
        this.Scor = iScor;
    }
//this is the toString added to diplay name and score 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Name + " " + Scor;
    }

}
```

and the exectution code from the button click

```
//begin button click
public void sorteazaCLICK(View view) {

    //initialization of textvies for place1 to place 4
    TextView varPozitia1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc1);
    TextView varPozitia2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc2);
    TextView varPozitia3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc3);
    TextView varPozitia4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_loc4);

    //initialization for name of players
    TextView varNumeJucator1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc1);
    String sNameJuc1;
    sNameJuc1 = varNumeJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varNumeJucator2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc2);
    String sNameJuc2;
    sNameJuc2 = varNumeJucator2.getText().toString();

    TextView varNumeJucator3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc3);
    String sNameJuc3;
    sNameJuc3 = varNumeJucator3.getText().toString();

    TextView varNumeJucator4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_numeJuc4);
    String sNameJuc4;
    sNameJuc4 = varNumeJucator4.getText().toString();

    //initialization of scores
    TextView varScorJucator1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc1);
    String t1;
    t1 = varScorJucator1.getText().toString();

    TextView varScorJucator2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc2);
    String t2;
    t2 = varScorJucator2.getText().toString();

    TextView varScorJucator3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc3);
    String t3;
    t3 = varScorJucator3.getText().toString();

    TextView varScorJucator4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_scorJuc4);
    String t4;
    t4 = varScorJucator4.getText().toString();


    //transformation scores into integer values
    int iScorJuc1;
    iScorJuc1 = Integer.parseInt(t1);

    int iScorJuc2;
    iScorJuc2 = Integer.parseInt(t2);

    int iScorJuc3;
    iScorJuc3 = Integer.parseInt(t3);

    int iScorJuc4;
    iScorJuc4 = Integer.parseInt(t4);


    ArrayList<JucatorScor> arrJucatorScor = new ArrayList<>(4);


    //manually construct of the object array list
    arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc1, iScorJuc1));  //position 0
    arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc2, iScorJuc2));  //position 1
    arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc3, iScorJuc3));  //position 2
    arrJucatorScor.add(new JucatorScor(sNameJuc4, iScorJuc4));  //position 3

    Collections.sort(arrJucatorScor, new Comparator<JucatorScor>() {

        //the sort of the object list by their scores
        @Override
        public int compare(JucatorScor o1, JucatorScor o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.Scor).compareTo(o2.Scor);
        }

    });


    //here are displayed in the position place1 to place4 from bigger score to smaller score
    varPozitia1.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(3)));
    varPozitia2.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(2)));
    varPozitia3.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(1)));
    varPozitia4.setText(String.valueOf(arrJucatorScor.get(0)));


}//end button click
```

Thanks very much for the help.